# Woocommerce Shop Price Position

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using Storefront theme with woocommerce and I want to create a custom layout in the shop page.

This custom layout has no product thumbnail the title and price must be inside the same div so I can easily customize it with css.

However when I try to get the price inside the h2 tags it doesn't has the result I expected. It appears but above the Title and outside the custom div. What am I doing wrong?

See image for reference
[image: image for reference]

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' , 'custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10);

function custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_title () {
    echo '
    <div class="custom-title-wrapper">
    <h1 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title custom-loop-product-title">' . get_the_title() . '</h1>
    <h2>' . woocommerce_template_loop_price() . '</h2>
    </div>'
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It appears but above the Title and outside the custom div. What am I
>   doing wrong?

It's because `woocommerce_template_loop_price()` echoes the output.

So to fix the problem, just use `?> HTML here <?php` instead of `echo 'HTML here';`:

```
function custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
    ?>
    <div class="custom-title-wrapper">
        <h1 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title custom-loop-product-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <h2><?php woocommerce_template_loop_price(); ?></h2>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

And (although this isn't a big issue,) you should use `add_action()` and not `add_filter()` because `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` is an action and not a filter:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
```

Comment: Thank you @user165319! It was indeed a great help and very well explained !

Comment: You're welcome, and I'd appreciate it if you can mark the answer as correct. :-)

Comment: Done! :)
I'd like to upvote your answer as well but my low reputation doesn't allow me to :(

Comment: Thanks! And it's alright about the upvote. :-)